# Recursive Chmod not working PHP

Tags: php, function, chmod

I have the below PHP function that should recursively chmod one of the dir's on my server.

For some reason it's not working - i know the path to the dir is correct as i've tested it with a quick script that just prints out the files within that dir.

```
$root_tmp = '/tmp/mixtape2'; 
chmod_r($root_tmp);

function chmod_r($Path) {
$dp = opendir($Path);
while($File = readdir($dp)) {
  if($File != "." AND $File != "..") {
     if(is_dir($File)){
        chmod($File, 0777);
        chmod_r($Path."/".$File);
     }else{
         chmod($Path."/".$File, 0777);
     }
  }
closedir($dp);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought... Does it matter that the dir i'm dealing with the the /tmp dir of the server?
So, i'm wondering if it's a permission issue?

For example, if i was at a terminal would i have to `sudo`? if so, how do i go about this from a php script?

Comment: Ok, i've just checked and the owner of the file that is executing this script is 'nginx' and the user of the files/folders i'm trying to chmod is 'root'. 
I guess i need to to change user somehow? 
Unfortunately, this is all new to me so i have no idea where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod($Path.'/'.$File, 0777);
```

You must put full path to chmod

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... 
So, at the moment i'm passing it the dir from $root_tmp which is relative to the where function is being run from.
I've changed this to `$root_tmp = '/tmp/mixtape2` and it's still not working. Does it matter that there are sub-folders inside the mixtape2 dir?

Comment: What does it mean 'not working'? It's not setting chmod or something?
use var_dump(chmod(..));
Also, from documentation: "When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the files or directories you are about to operate on have the same UID (owner) as the script that is being executed. In addition, you cannot set the SUID, SGID and sticky bits."

Comment: yes, it's not setting the chmod. 
If i add in `var_dump` then it gives me 'bool(false) <path/filename>'

I'm thinking this may be a user permissions issue as per my comment on my original question

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script is executed by the webserver, which most probably has its own user on your system. Since the files you are trying to chmod() are owned by root, you don't have the right to chmod them. You need to go into your filesystem first, and chown these files to the correct user and group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... i've just been searching Google and come across the `chown` function.
I have tried a standard `chown($root_tmp, 'nginx');` which in my head should change the user to that of the executing file mentioned earlier. 
However, this didn't work.
I have then also tried `exec('chown nginx /tmp/mixtape2');` which also didn't work.
I presume this again due to me running these scripts from the webserver user.
Any pointers on where to go from here?

Comment: You need to actually log in on the server, and change these files using a filemanager, of using the command line. "chown -R nginx:nginx FILENAME" should do the trick.

Comment: The problem with that is that this is a tmp directory that has files created everytime we run a certain function on our site.
Doing it via command line will only `chown` the files that are there right now... any new files that are created will be created by 'root' again won't they?
That's why i was looking for a PHP solution as i was going to build in in to a function that chown's, chmod's and then unlink's the files.

Comment: Right... have you tried doing a 'sudo chmod'? You can edit the /etc/sudoers file to grant your webserver user sudo rights without password. However, that's a dangerous road to go down of course...

Comment: i did think about giving sudo access but as you say that's not really the best option... perhaps i would be better off looking at a cronjob for this task?

Comment: If you have the chance to do that, I'd indeed opt for the cron job. The chowning is not a resource intensive task, so you should be able to run it quite frequently without clogging up the system.