# How to allow access to sub folders in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have laravel installed on my server and I want to add a folder called 'projects' in laravel's root folder and access the projects folder from URL.

What should I do to solve this issue? I want to upload some PHP code demos and allow people to view them.

I have tried playing with the .htaccess but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive Chmod not working PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211033/recursive-chmod-not-working-php)

Answer (score 0):

public_path(); // Path of public/

base_path(); // Path of application root

app_path(); // Path of app/